# Propositional logic "equivalent to" using union, intersection and negation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In the Maths book, "implies to" is described as

$A\rightarrow$B equals to $\lnot\ A \lor  B $

How can I represent $A \Leftrightarrow B$ in the same way?

Comment: What do you mean by "union, intersection, and negation"?  Do you mean the propositional connectives conjunction, disjunction, and negation?  Or do you mean the sets union, intersection, and complement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \iff B$ is equivalent to $( \neg A \lor B ) \land ( \neg B \lor A )$

which in turn is equivalent to $( \neg A \land \neg B ) \lor ( A \land B )$

Answer (score 2):

If you think about the propositions as sets, then $A\iff B$ is the same as $A=B$.